# The physical meaning of the $L^2$ norm of the gradient of the velocity in N-S equation

Tags: navier-stokes

I'm reading [Asymptotic Properties of Steady Plane Solutions
of the Navier-Stokes Equations
with Bounded Dirichlet Integral](http://www.numdam.org/item/ASNSP_1978_4_5_2_381_0.pdf) written by D. GILBARG and H. F. WEINBERGER. They studied the properties of an arbitrary solution $\{\boldsymbol{w}, p\}$ of the two-dimensional Navier-Stokes equations
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Delta \boldsymbol{w}-(\boldsymbol{w} \cdot \nabla) \boldsymbol{w} & =\nabla p \\
\nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{w} & =\mathbf{0},
\end{aligned}
$$
in a neighborhood of infinity, which has the property that
$$
\int_{r>r_0}|\nabla \boldsymbol{w}|^2 d x d y<\infty .
$$
I want to ask what is the physical meaning of the $
\int_{r>r_0}|\nabla \boldsymbol{w}|^2 d x d y<\infty .
$ I read something about the velocity gradient [What Is Velocity Gradient](https://unacademy.com/content/jee/study-material/physics/dimensional-formula-of-velocity-gradient/), but I want to know whether the $L^2$ norm of the velocity gradient has physical meaning, or this is just some asymptotic conditions on the velocity gradient.

Comment: $w$ is a vector, so $\nabla w$ is a tensor; which tensor norm do you mean by $|\nabla w|^2$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I have deleted the question on mathstackexchange, $\boldsymbol{w}=(u,v)$, then $|\nabla \boldsymbol{w}|^2 = |\nabla u|^2+|\nabla v|^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quantity that has a physical significance in a fluid is the norm of the [strain rate tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strain-rate_tensor) $E$, with elements
$$E_{ij}=\tfrac{1}{2}(\partial w_i/\partial x_j+\partial w_j/\partial x_i).$$
For a two-dimensional velocity field $w=(u,v)$ the [(Frobenius) norm](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNorm.html) of the strain rate tensor is
$$\| E\|^2=\sum_{i,j}E_{ij}^2=|\nabla u|^2+|\nabla v|^2-\tfrac{1}{2}|\nabla\times w|^2.$$
In the OP the curl of the velocity field is not included, I think it should be for a physically meaningful quantity.